# How to convert my data column to numerical values

Tags: r

I`m just a beginner in using r, and want to ask you how to convert my glucose datatable values (yes/no) into numerical values 1 and 2. Like this; yes=1 and no=2 in my data tetrahymena.txt. Here is a bit of my code if it is helpfull;

```
cell <- read.table(file="tetrahymena.txt", header=TRUE, sep="\t", dec = ".")
cell

#attach(cell)
colnames(cell) <- c("glucose","conc","diameter")
#x1, concentration of cells
#x2, glucose added (yes=1, no=2)
#y, diameter (micrometer)

summary(cell)

cell <- c(glucose,"yes=1","no=2")
summary(cell)
```

Comment: `cell$glucose = ifelse(cell$glucose == "yes", 1, 0)`.

Comment: Depending on your use, you may prefer (in most cases this will be better) a logical type to a numeric.  Then you can do `cell$glucose <- cell$glucose == "yes"`

Comment: Big thanks guys @dww and Gregor !!!!

Comment: Don't use `attach`. You have been warned.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a factor
Type "?factor" to learn more.  But this is an R object that combines character labels and an underlying order.

Below are two methods.  The first uses a factor, which is a but more general purpose.  The second sets 'yes' and 'no' to 1 and 0 manually

## Method 1: Use Factors

(1) Creates a 'glucose' data.frame with yesses and nos 
(2) sets a factor and sets all possible values/levels to 'no' or 'yes' and labels them with the character string of '0' and '1'
(3) since the factor labels are characters, convert these to explicit characters and remove the factor level information with as.character() and then convert to numeric values with as.numeric()

```
glucose <- data.frame(cell=c("yes","yes","no","no","yes","no","yes"))
glucose$cellfactor <- factor(x=glucose$cell,levels=c("no","yes"),labels=c(0,1))
glucose$cellvalue <- as.numeric(as.character(glucose$cellfactor))

glucose
```

## Method 2: Set the value manually

(1) Create a data.frame of yesses and nos
(2) Find all the 'yes' values and set a $cellvalue column to 1
(3) Find all the 'no' values and set the $cellvalue colunmn to 0

```
glucose <- data.frame(cell=c("yes","yes","no","no","yes","no","yes"))
glucose$cellvalue[glucose$cell=="yes"] <- 1
glucose$cellvalue[glucose$cell=="no"] <- 0

glucose
```